# SQL Query not inserting

Tags: php, html, sql

So I've written this query to insert some data into my table which is called "character_table". I am inserting inputs from several fields on a click of a button to my SQL database. But for some reason, the query is not running, there are no error messages currently.

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO character_table(char_name,char_class,char_prim_wep,char_sec_wep,char_gen_type) ";
    $query .= "VALUES ('$char_name', '$char_class', '$char_prim_wep', '$char_sec_wep', '$char_gen_type') ";
    $insert_first_query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if(!$insert_first_query){
            die("Query Failed" . mysqli_error($db));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you try in a single line?

Comment: @aziz that shouldn't make a difference?

Comment: From the code that you've shown, I can't see anything wrong. Could it be something else?

Comment: There is no wrong with code, may be something wrong with your database schema. Check datatype and character limit in your database table structure or try to run sql query direct on phpmyadmin, and check for error.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and  `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script to see the mysqli error.

Comment: Is that point character `.` a typo in the second line, inside of `$query .=`?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan no, that is correct syntax to add on to a string.

Comment: Even if there is no syntax error in your code, I would consider it a bad practice. Your query is vunerable to SQL injection if the inputs are from sources that you can not control (user inputs, for example). Try to write your query with prepare statement with either mysql i or preferably PDO.

Comment: I have the display errors on and nothing is showing there, also I have not got round to preventing my sql queries from injection.

Comment: `var_dump($query); die();` and then run this query in console or any GUI tool like Adminer or phpMyAdmin.